# switch from a td to input and back on td with new value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kinda new with this.

below code is running

switch `td` to input and can edit values work when click enter button and back to `td` with new values but when on mouse click it just show input html code no values

```
<script>

    $('td').dblclick(function (tdin) {
        var td_data =  $(this).html();
        var td_dtin =  $(this).html('<input type="text" value='+td_data+'>');
        $('input').keyup(function (enter) {
            var td_edit =  $(this).val();
                if (enter.which === 13) {
                    var td_edit =  $(this).val();
                    $(this).hide(); 
                    var inin=  $(this).replaceWith(td_edit);
                }
        })
    })

</script>
```

Comment: try `var td_data = $(this).text()` on your td_data line

Comment: yeah , ty , it did work

Comment: cool! I added my comment as a full answer since this solved your problem. Accepting it will help others with this same problem find the solution quicker ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

```js
$('td').dblclick(function (tdin) {
    var td_data =  $(this).html();

    // rest of code...
})
```